# How to Use the Customize window to add third party applications in Datastage

Tags: datastage

How to Use the Customize window to add third party applications in Datastage? My team is doing a research on how to integrate Datastage with bitbucket and wants to know how the Custom feature in Datastage can be used for this. Appreciate if anyone could provide some examples on how to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Customize** from the Options menu then, in the Customize dialog box, click **Help**. All will be revealed.